# Selenium python code to click button on interactive map for web scraping not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to web scrape data from an interactive map using Selenium in python. I have been having difficulties with the code to click certain buttons to get to the data. The first "click" works fine, but the second is not working. I have tried adjusting the time and nothing is working. I want to be able to do that second click. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
Here is my code:

```
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import sys
import re
import csv
import time
import shutil
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options) 

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
import time
wd.maximize_window()
wd.get("https://hazards.geoplatform.gov/portal/apps/MapSeries/index.html?appid=ddf915a24fb24dc8863eed96bc3345f8")
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-bar"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a'))))
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="widgets_About_Widget_34"]/div/div/div/div[10]/font/a'))))
```

### The error occurs on the last line, and here is the full error:

TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
7 wd.get("https://hazards.geoplatform.gov/portal/apps/MapSeries/index.html?appid=ddf915a24fb24dc8863eed96bc3345f8")
8 wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-bar"]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9caG.jpg)/ul/li[4]/a'))))
----> 9 wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(wd, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="widgets_About_Widget_34"]/div/div/div/div[10]/font/a'))))
10
11

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
78             if time.time() > end_time:
79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
81
82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:

Here is the image of what I want to click: "Census Tracts Table" [Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9caG.jpg)

Comment: Please let me know if this resolved your problem.

Comment: Hello, this unfortunately did not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

1. The main blocker avoiding you from access the second element is because it is inside an iframe, so to acceess it you first have to switch to that iframe.
2. Your locators are bad.
3. Don't click elements with JavaScript until you have no alternative.
4. In headless mode you have to define the screen size.
5. `wd.maximize_window()` is used for normal mode, not headless.
   So you code should be something like this:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import sys
import re
import csv
import time
import shutil
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options) 

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
import time
#wd.maximize_window()
wd.get("https://hazards.geoplatform.gov/portal/apps/MapSeries/index.html?appid=ddf915a24fb24dc8863eed96bc3345f8")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'entry  visible')]//a[contains(text(),'Data Download Tool')]"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='mainMediaContainer active']>iframe")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[title='Download']"))).click()
```

Comment: I have edited this several times. Now it should work. Also I guess this solution is better...

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. However, this code is still not working for me and I am confused with using CSS. I actually found an easier second click than the one I had before. Now the 2 clicks are this: 1. wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-bar"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a'))))
2. wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(wd, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="widgets_About_Widget_34"]/div/div/div/div[10]/font/a'))))
The first click works, but the second doesn't.

Comment: Please post the code inside the question to make it readable

Comment: Also, when running the code that you provided, I am getting the following error: MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35089): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/f98930adcbf12e63b916d1d1def06c8b/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f37f30d2d10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: I'm not sure this caused by my code... Also, again, don't use JavaScript clicks until you have no alternative. You should use `driver.click()` since only this method mimics user GUI actions

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have updated the code in the question to reflect the new code. I appreciate your help. And when running your code, I am still getting the following error: MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35089): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/f98930adcbf12e63b916d1d1def06c8b/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f37f3160cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')) Would you be able to update your code now that I changed the second click in my code?

Comment: This error not caused by my code. 100%. I do not know how to resolve this issue, but it is definitely not caused by changes I did.

Comment: When I run your code I still get an error on this line unfortunately: wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'entry  visible')]//a[contains(text(),'Data Download Tool')]"))).click()
. If you are unable to help with this, would someone else be able to?

Comment: Here is the error: MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35089): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/f98930adcbf12e63b916d1d1def06c8b/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f37f337f550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: I also added an image of what I'm trying to click, in my question.

Comment: Again, this error is not caused by my code.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know why it's not working on my end or what else I could do for it to work.

Comment: This will not work in the same way for any other actions on that site. It's connection issue, not accessing the elements on the site

Answer (score 0):

The `Download` button is in the 4th `iframe`. Below code did click on the `Download` icon.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://hazards.geoplatform.gov/portal/apps/MapSeries/index.html? appid=ddf915a24fb24dc8863eed96bc3345f8")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='nav-bar']/div/div/ul/li[4]/a").click()
driver.switch_to.frame(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@settingid='widgets_Query_Widget_32']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Find census tracts']").click()
```